# Unmet dependency nodejs 8

Tags: node.js, dependencies, ibm-cloud

When I want to deploy my application on `Bluemix`, I get and error :unmet dependency

If I use node js 6.x, there no more error, but just with node 8.x.
[image]

in my package json

```
     "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "cassandra-driver": "^3.4.1",
    "cfenv": "1.0.x",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "4.13.x",
    "express-session": "^1.15.1",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "saml2-js": "^1.12.2",
    "soap": "^0.25.0",
    "urlencode": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Any idea please to resolve the problem with node 8

Answer (score 0):

Before the push, you might want to try

```
$ ic cf set-env myApp NODE_MODULES_CACHE false
```